# Sikuli selenium with eclipse

Tags: eclipse, selenium, task, sikuli

I would like to automate simple process to fill an internet form.
I use the `Eclipse` environment with `Sikuli` and `Selenium` for this purpose.
I follow the following tutorial. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8y41vKeGM9U
Still after writing the following code it do not seems to connect and open Google Chrome. With several problems: red cross on the class and project name icones, pattern cannot be resolved to a type. It seems to me that it cannot properly connect and perform while I think that I installed all the useful .jar files. I could be wrong on that. If you could help please. Thanks.

```
import org.sikuli.script.Screen;

public class FillForm {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        Screen screen = new Screen();
        Pattern pattern = new Pattern("C:\\Users\\mahfo\\Documents\\Sikuli project\\Pictures\\LoginShizugin.PNG");
        Pattern pattern1 = new Pattern("C:\\Users\\mahfo\\Documents\\Sikuli project\\Pictures\\LoginShizugin1.PNG");
        Pattern pattern2 = new Pattern("C:\\Users\\mahfo\\Documents\\Sikuli project\\Pictures\\LoginShizugin1.PNG");
        Pattern pattern3 = new Pattern("C:\\Users\\mahfo\\Documents\\Sikuli project\\Pictures\\LoginShizugin1.PNG");
        Pattern pattern4 = new Pattern("C:\\Users\\mahfo\\Documents\\Sikuli project\\Pictures\\LoginShizugin1.PNG");
        Pattern pattern5 = new Pattern("C:\\Users\\mahfo\\Documents\\Sikuli project\\Pictures\\LoginShizugin1.PNG");
        Pattern pattern6 = new Pattern("C:\\Users\\mahfo\\Documents\\Sikuli project\\Pictures\\LoginShizugin1.PNG");
        Pattern pattern7 = new Pattern("C:\\Users\\mahfo\\Documents\\Sikuli project\\Pictures\\LoginShizugin1.PNG");
        Pattern pattern8 = new Pattern("C:\\Users\\mahfo\\Documents\\Sikuli project\\Pictures\\LoginShizugin1.PNG");


        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\mahfo\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32.zip\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.******************.co.**/0149c/rblgi01/I1RBLGI01-S01.do");
        screen.wait(pattern, 5000);
        screen.type(pattern, "*****");
        screen.click(pattern1); 
        screen.click(pattern2);
        screen.type(pattern3, "***********");
        screen.click(pattern4);
        screen.click(pattern5);
        screen.click(pattern6);
        screen.click(pattern7);
        screen.click(pattern8);
```

Comment: try pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</> to automatically resolve types. This will work only if the required classes are already in your class path. If that doesn't happen, then you know you have not imported the classes properly. Another option is to use Maven to take care of the dependencies. That will be the right approach.

Answer (score 0):

Below steps worked for me, please check whether you added this jar to your project build path

1. Download Sikulixsetup-1.1.0.jar from launchpad.net/sikuli/+download website
2. Click on that jar to setup. After installing that, add sikulixapi.jar as external jar in Buildpath.

or
You can try with maven dependency if it is configured as maven project. I didn't try with this dependency, just try this if you want:
mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.sikuli/sikuli-core/1.0.0, try this.

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.sikuli/sikuli-core --> 
    <dependency> 
    <groupId>org.sikuli</groupId>
    <artifactId>sikuli-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
```